# Correct typos with R

Tags: r

The following example is great to correct typos when you have a limited number of possible correct answers. In this case the expected answer can only be one of the following: positive, negative, neutral

```
# Example of data typed manually that is prone to typos
typed_manually <- c("Positive", "positive ", "Positive", " positives", "neurtal", "negativv", "high")

# To lower case
typed_manually <- tolower(typed_manually)

# We specify what are the expected correct values
expected_answers <- c("positive", "negative", "neutral")

# Associate typed_manually to expected_answers using a max distance of 2.
# amatch is preferable to the adist function because letter permutations only count as distance =1
library(stringdist)
(i <- amatch(typed_manually,expected_answers,maxDist=2))

## Compare side by side values typed manually and corrections
data.frame(rawtext = typed_manually, code = expected_answers[i])
```

However, for many variables, we can't give a list of expected answers.
For instance if the variable is the Employer of the person filling a form.

What do you recommend in those situations?

Do you think a system that starts with the most obvious errors and ask you if you want to merge these values is most suited?

A text like the following would appear in the console:
" "Coca-Cola Company" and "Cocal-Cola company" are most similar.
Press "1" to merge them to "Coca-Cola Company" and "2" to merge them to "Cocal-Cola company". Enter "skip" to skip to next proposition"

Would it make sense to have the order based on this ratio? 
String distance/ word length

Is there a smarter approach? Is there's already a package doing this? How could we implement this?

Thanks!

Note A: Code above is heavily inspired from http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/de_Jonge+van_der_Loo-Introduction_to_data_cleaning_with_R.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, where the `jarowinkler` function gives you more discrimination than `amatch` as to which choices are closer to the expected answers.

```
library(RecordLinkage)
jaro <- sapply(typed_manually, FUN = function(x) (jarowinkler(expected_answers, x, r = 0.5)))  
rownames(jaro) <- expected_answers
jaro.df <- t(as.data.frame(jaro))

> jaro.df
            positive  negative   neutral
positive   1.0000000 0.5833333 0.4226190
positive   0.9777778 0.5648148 0.4179894
positive   1.0000000 0.5833333 0.4226190
 positives 0.9333333 0.5500000 0.4142857
neurtal    0.4226190 0.6857143 0.9666667
negativv   0.4722222 0.9500000 0.6857143
high       0.4583333 0.4583333 0.0000000
```

Comment: This is indeed better when you have the expected answers. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help.  I didn't figure out how to create a data frame that compares the raw entry to the jaro-found match with the highest value.  Your final line of code was what I tried for a while to imitate.